# Regression with dependent variable as a factor variable

Tags: r

I had a data set that I am trying to carry out a regression for. I have created this command however I get the following error message on running it.

```
ols3<- lm(health~age, data= Wage)
```

Warning messages:

1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored

2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

I need to find the residual of age in this scenario, could someone please help me with the mistake I'm making here?

Comment: how does health, age look like? Cheap way would be to do as.numeric(age), however, if health, age is in "classes" (as the hint to factor tells you) there might be no proper interpretation of the result

Comment: So age is numeric, however health is a class

Comment: You should use something like multinominal logit or so. Regression is for continuous outcomes